# Compare date with numpy vectorize does not work

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I would like to compare dates using np.vectorize but it is not working.

When a date is equal to "1800-10-10 00:00:00" I want to return False if not I want to return True

I need to do it with `np.vectorize`

Here is my dataframe :

```
Name = ["Mark",'Eart','Frop','John','MArk']
dateList=["1800-10-10 00:00:00","1800-10-10 00:00:00","1900-10-10 00:00:00",None,None]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Name, dateList)), columns =['Name', 'Date'])
```

Here is how I fill empties columns and keep date format:

```
df=df.fillna('NULL')
df['Date']=df['Date'].replace('NULL', '1800-10-10 00:00:00')
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors = 'coerce',format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Here is the function that helps me to return False  if the date is '1800-10-10 00:00:00' :

```
def ISColFilled(x):
  
  date_string = "1800-10-10 00:00:00"
  date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  if(x==date):
    return False
  else :
    return True
```

Here is how I want to use it :

```
ISColFilled_V=np.vectorize(ISColFilled)
df['Date_Det']=ISColFilled_V(df['Date'].values)
```

But this is not working :

```
print(df)

    Name    Date    Date_Det
0   Mark    1800-10-10  True
1   Eart    1800-10-10  True
2   Frop    1900-10-10  True
3   John    1800-10-10  True
4   MArk    1800-10-10  True
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you absolutely need to use `np.vectorize`?

Comment: I think you expect `np.vectorize` to be faster, isn't it? But the truth is, it is almost never significantly faster in practice (mainly since it calls a pure Python function).

Comment: Does this function work with a single row?  Can you use pandas `apply` (or some other iterator)?  If the dates are in `np.datetime64` format, the whole `values` array can be tested without (explicit) iteration.